# Determinant of a $3\times 3$ real symmetric matrix

Tags: matrices, determinant, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

Let $A$ be a real symmetric $3\times 3$ matrix with entries belonging to the set of non-negative integers. Also assume that each diagonal entries are greater than or equal to all the entries in the row and column in which the diagonal entry belongs.

I want to know whether all the eigenvalues of the matrix is non-negative, i.e., it is a positive semidefinite matrix or not.

Note that this is true if we consider the $2\times 2$ matrices of the above type. I just want to know whether this is true for $3\times 3$ case.

Comment: Note that all eigenvalues being nonnegative and the determinant being nonnegative are not equivalent in the $3\times 3$ case. Also, for nonnegativity of all eigenvalues: if the diagonal entries are greater than or equal to the row (and/or column) sums, then Gershgorin's theorem implies the result.

Comment: When you say "each diagonal entries are greater than or equal to all the entries" do you mean each diagonal is greater than or equal to _each_ entry in a corresponding row or column? Or do you mean the diagonal entry is greater than the _sum_ of the nondiagonal entries in the corresponding row or column?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not true. The following matrix, for example, has a negative determinant (and therefore a negative eigenvalue).
$$\begin{bmatrix}1&1&0\\ 1&2&2\\ 0&2&2\end{bmatrix}$$

Its determinant is $-2$.